# wierd pixelation of Finder icons in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I am getting a strange graphics issue on Mavericks with the Finder and it also happens in the Application Switcher. I have rebooted but not really sure what to do next. It's clearly many of them so probably more systemic than just a corrupted single file. Any ideas on what is going on or how to fix?

### edit #1

having spent about an hour and a few reboots, it has really just been the finder bar and application switcher (and only specific icons amongst those - the actual icons don't change). any other ideas appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe OS X's icons are cached by an OS subsystem called Launch Services. Try rebuilding the Launch Services cache:

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

These instructions are from Mountain Lion. I haven't tried them on Mavericks yet, but I suspect they'll be the same.

Comment: amazing! thx so much - looks like it fixed it!